# ¿Cómo puedo añadir nuevos campos a los objetos de un archivo JSON existente?

Tags: javascript, json, nodejs

Estoy trabajando con NodeJS, tengo un archivo JSON definido como:

```
let points = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./points.json', 'utf8'));
```

Con el siguiente formato:

```
{
  "242043489611808769":{"points":617,"level":4,"time":1482316617392},
  "129213229221019648":{"points":22,"level":0,"time":1482316617609},
  "190388892799598592":{"points":214,"level":2,"time":1482316612355}
}
```

El cual tiene su **id** correspondiente y 3 campos (si no se llaman así corríjame, por favor), "points", "level" y "time", ahora resulta que quiero añadir dos campos nuevos, "color" y "money". ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo sin añadirlo manualmente?

Comment: Desde donde quieres agregarlo? Desde jquery? Como lo trabajas en jquery? Desde node? Es un archivo? Por favor especifica mas

Comment: En las etiquetas puse NodeJS. En la primera línea puse "Tengo un archivo JSON". Actualizado, perdón, no había puesto cómo definí el archivo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var json = {
  "242043489611808769":{"points":617,"level":4,"time":1482316617392},
  "129213229221019648":{"points":22,"level":0,"time":1482316617609},
  "190388892799598592":{"points":214,"level":2,"time":1482316612355}
}

for(var t in json){
    json[t]["color"] = "blue";
    json[t]["money"] = "10000";
}

console.log(json);

fs.writeFile('./points.json', JSON.stringify(json));
```

Answer (score 1):

Asumo que querés repetir los valores de tus nueva propiedades. Para color coloque verde y para money 18099. Podes usarlo con nodeJS o en JavaScript puro

```
var jsonObj = {
    "242043489611808769":{"points":617,"level":4,"time":1482316617392},
    "129213229221019648":{"points":22,"level":0,"time":1482316617609},
    "190388892799598592":{"points":214,"level":2,"time":1482316612355}
}

for(var indice in jsonObj ){
    jsonObj[indice]["color"] = "verde";
    jsonObj[indice]["money"] = "18099";
}
console.log(jsonObj);
```